# Which values are making the conversion from VARCHAR to DATE fail?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am reading a value from a key/value table that should contain a NULLABLE date with the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The simplified version of the query is.

```
SELECT CAST(ClaimDate AS DATE) AS ClaimDate
FROM MyTable
```

This leads to the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I have tried `CONVERT(DATE, ClaimDate)` as well to no avail.

Now, more than knowing why I get this error, I am curious to know which values are causing this.

I have seen several questions regarding the error message above. But I haven't found the one giving an answer to my problem.

Of course, suggesting a solution in addition to getting bad values is highly appreciated.

Comment: Order by Claimdate and make sure all values are greater than A.D. 1754,  Dates before that will not convert to datetime.

Comment: "Should" doesn't mean "does". Use `TRY_CAST` to find which rows contain invalid entries

Comment: @RobertSievers they *can*. `select cast('1400-01-01' as date)` works

Comment: The fact that you are doing `CAST(ClaimDate AS DATE)` means that you have a "Date" column that isn't storing data as a `date(time)`. That is your *real* problem here. `varchar` is not a one size fits all data type. You need to fix your data type definotions.

Comment: The real solution is to convert that field to `date` instead of using varchar. Unfortunately, the  `yyyy-MM-dd` format is *not* locale agnostic. The way it's parsed is affected by [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The truly agnostic format is `YYYYMMdd` or the full ISO8601 format, `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. If you're absolutely certain there are no `2019-14-03` entries in there, you can use `PARSE(ClaimDate as date USING 'en-GB')` or any other locale except `en-US`

Comment: By `MM` do you mean `Jan` instead of `01`?

Comment: It can happen when trying to convert non-sensible dates such as Feb 30th, and other reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your SQL Server version (2012+), you can use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT ClaimDate 
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  TRY_CONVERT(DATE, ClaimDate ) IS NULL
    AND ClaimDate IS NOT NULL
```

This will give you the values that can't be converted to a date, how you're going to solve those issues is another question. Also, a value of `2019-01-12` may be converted, but if it's in a string you cannot be sure whether this is a date in December or in January. You may get valid but wrong dates!

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: WIll accept as answer as soon as Stack allows me to .

Comment: @disasterkid are you *sure*? What do these rows contain? Perhaps you're in the US and DATEFORMAT is YMD, which would fail on `2019-03-14`. Ignoring the conversion error will mean that you end up with March 4th instead of April 3rd

Answer (score 0):

As others explained, the real problem is using `varchar` instead of `date` as the type. This allowed bad data to be inserted in the field. Fixing this may not be possible - what if there are strings using different date formats in different rows?

`CAST(ClaimDate AS DATE)` can fail if the text field contains a non-date string. In this case, the rows can be ignored with :

```
SELECT ClaimDate AS ClaimDate
FROM MyTable
where TRY_CAST(ClaimDate as date) is not null
```

It's fortunate that the type is `date`. `datetime` parsing is affected by the [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) setting. If it was set to YDM, this line would still work :

```
set dateformat ydm;

select cast('2019-03-14' as date);
```

While this would throw

```
set dateformat ydm;

select cast('2019-03-14' as datetime);
```

Things would be a lot worse if the value was `2019-03-04`. Instead of throwing, the cast would return the wrong date.

Fortunately, from DATEFORMAT's remarks :

> The DATEFORMAT ydm isn't supported for date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset data types.

That's why the failing data should be checked first with

```
SELECT ClaimDate AS ClaimDate
FROM MyTable
where TRY_CAST(ClaimDate as date) is not null
```

If everything is OK, the type should be changed to `date` to ensure bad values can't be inserted