# TRY_CONVERT returns NULL on a value that looks like a date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

I have been benefiting from `TRY_CONVERT` function thanks to [a reply from my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185477/which-values-are-making-the-conversion-from-varchar-to-date-fail).

I am now facing a value in a key/value table (the value column of type `NVARCHAR(50)`) that cannot be converted to `DATE` even though it very much looks like a date.

[image]

I'd like to why `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [Claim issue complete])` should return a `NULL`.

Even though I use a substring of the value like this the result is the same

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Claim issue complete], 1, 10) AS CompletionDate
```

**UPDATE**: A textual copy of the picture

```
Claim issue complete
2018-09-21 00:00:00+02
2017-10-12 00:00:00+02
2018-01-30 00:00:00+01
2017-07-19 00:00:00+02
2019-02-14 00:00:00+01
NULL
2017-08-06 00:00:00+02
2017-10-04 00:00:00+02
2018-05-18 00:00:00+02
2018-09-05 00:00:00+02
2019-01-14 00:00:00+01
2019-01-24 00:00:00+01
2018-03-21 00:00:00+01
2017-11-28 00:00:00+01
2018-02-26 00:00:00+01
2018-04-05 00:00:00+02
2018-04-27 00:00:00+02
```

**Update 2**: An Example

Here is a sample of the problem.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '2018-09-21 00:00:00+02')
```

The above returns `NULL`.

Comment: Is it a specific value where the conversion fails, or all/some of them? Can you create a [mcve] with DDL+DML for sample data so that we could reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ZoharPeled the values in the picture all return a `NULL` for `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [Claim issue complete])`.

Comment: Well, I can't copy the values from the picture into a test environment, so I really can't see what the problem actually is.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sure. Sorry! I will paste the values in the question. I just hope no hidden characters are involved.

Comment: @ZoharPeled question updated with text for the dates.

Comment: Are you saying that the substring also returns null?

Comment: *even though it very much looks like a date*!! Post the problematic value.

Comment: Just because something "looks" like a date, doesn't mean SQL Server will always convert it. For example `TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '2019-03-17')` and `TRY_CONVERT(date,'03/17/2019')` would both return `NULL` on my instance. There only 2 formats that guarentee the **correct** conversion regardless of data type and language; and they are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-dd-Thh:mm:ss.sssssss`. You haven't actually the value that is returning `NULL` here; so all we can tell you is that  the date string isn't valid.

Comment: Can you post the value for which the query returns NULL? Most probably it is invalid for this type of operation.

Comment: @AnaIulianaTuhasu yes, please see the new update with a sample value.

Comment: @forpas please look at the Update 2 i the question.

Comment: @Larnu please look at the Update 2 i the question.

Comment: But you were using `SUBSTRING`, which does work. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45ae6848e74383ef1cdfdeacbb4250cf)

Comment: @Larnu you are right. I just need to have a separate case for when the `[Claim issue complete]` is `NULL`. Because that would make `SUBSTRING` to return an error. You can write this as an answer.

Comment: `SUBSTRING` won't return an error is the value of the `varchar` is `NULL`. Are we missing a point of information here?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should change the database structure and store your values in the appropriate data type - if you need a date value store it as [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if you need it with time store it as [`DateTime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ([Why not `DateTime`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792766/date-conversion-and-culture-difference-between-date-and-datetime)) and if you need it to be time zone aware store it as [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

The string representation format you are using in your database does not fit any of the [built in date time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) in SQL Server - that's why the `Try_Convert` fails (as will `Try_Cast`, for that matter).
If you are only interested in the date part of the value, you can use `try_cast` on the 10 left-most chars - since you are casting to `Date` and not `DateTime` the yyyy-mm-dd format is unambiguous and will always be converted correctly:

```
SELECT  TRY_CAST(LEFT('2018-09-21 00:00:00+02', 10) As DATE)
```

If you want to use `Try_convert` instead, you need to specify the `style` parameter - 120 in this case:

```
SELECT  TRY_CONVERT(DATE, LEFT('2018-09-21 00:00:00+02', 10), 120)
```

Please note that you don't need any code to handle `null` inputs - they will just come out as `null`

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2 , '2018-09-21 00:00:00 +02', 20) -- null, since this '+02' is not a legit OFFSET
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2 , '2018-09-21 00:00:00 +02:00', 20) -- OK
--Solution for bad OFFSET style can be to add the missing string:
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2 , '2018-09-21 00:00:00 +02' + ':00', 20) -- OK

--Same using Date:
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE , '2018-09-21 00:00:00 +02' + ':00', 20) -- OK
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '2018-09-21 00:00:00+02')` is'nt working is cause it is'nt a valid date format. To be specific, it is the `+02` part in the end.
You could re-write it like this if you know the first 19 positions always will be `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, LEFT('2018-09-21 00:00:00+02', 19))
```

I've just added the `LEFT`-function to sort out the `+02` in the end